# how to convert, date change event into particular format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs, daterangepicker

I am having date in my site, and I am using dates using daterangepicker and moment js. Now I am new to all these things & one of the variable setting up date is as

```
moment().subtract(29, 'days')
```

whose `console.log` results into `1492930351644`,
similarly `moment()` result to `1495435951644`.

Now on manual change by the user I want, to update this values but however I don't know how to make use of it. I have used jQuery event as below

```
$('#dateRange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    var startDate_1 = moment.utc(startDateCal).format('LL');
    var endDate_1 = moment.utc(endDateCal).format('LL');

    dates.setData('startDateCal',startDate_1);  
    dates.setData('endDateCal',endDate_1); 

    console.log(" changed start date "+dates.getData('startDateCal'));
    console.log(" changed end date "+dates.getData('endDateCal'));

});
```

so when I change and select the date as today from view calender I am get into the above change event but my output would be

```
 changed start date May 21, 2017
 changed end date May 22, 2017
```

Here I want an output or date format similar to `1492930351644` as shown by `moment().subtract(29, 'days')` but I don't know how would I be able to achieve that. Any help?

Comment: Try add `$scope.$apply();` after `dates.setData`

Comment: so from my understanding you want the date in Unix Timestamp format ?

Comment: @ABiswas - No I am not looking for a unix date but the format as above which I do not know, how can I get using momentjs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to save the unix ms timestamp format as a `data-` attribute. You are doing it right, you just have to use the [`format` date](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) function like this:

```
moment.utc(startDateCal).format('x') // get the unix timestamp format
```

Or when you read the data back, you should create a moment object out of it and use `valueOf` to get the number format:

```
moment(dates.getData('startDateCal')).valueOf()
```

It seems like you are currently using a fixed `startDateCal` and `endDateCal`. I suggest to you to use the picker attribute in the callback function to get the actual date from the picker itself, like this:

```
$('#dateRange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    var startDate_1 = picker.startDate.format('x');
    var endDate_1 = picker.endDate.format('x');

    dates.setData('startDateCal',startDate_1);
    dates.setData('endDateCal',endDate_1);

    console.log(" changed start date "+dates.getData('startDateCal'));
    console.log(" changed end date "+dates.getData('endDateCal'));

});
```

Comment: but can I make that subtract part dynamic --- i.e I want to be able check what date difference was set to be able to update from any of my controllers ?!

Comment: getting error 
_Uncaught TypeError: dates.getData(...).getTime is not a function_

Comment: your answer seems to be, nearby but not correct as I am getting same value for all dates that  I am selecting `1495305000000 & 1493576999999 as start & end` same if I select today or last week.

Comment: I have updated the answer, it seems like you are using a fixed startDateCal, you should use the picker attribute itself from the callback function.

Comment: Thanks a ton. You saved my day, Amen !

Answer (score 0):

try this change .`format('LL')` to `.format('x')` i.e

```
var startDate_1 = moment.utc(startDateCal).format('x');
var endDate_1 = moment.utc(endDateCal).format('x');
```